# Undefined method despite including my module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this module:

```
module Moody
    def foo
        'bar'
    end
end
```

And yet in a controller:

```
class MyController   
  include Moody # this works. Including Moodasdasd causes a failure

  def index
    puts foo #=> expect 'bar' undefined local variable or method `foo' raised
  end
end
```

I get a undefined local variable or method error.

How should I include a module's methods in an action?

Comment: I replicated this, and it worked fine for me.(no error)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the module isn't being included in the application namespace?

I can't be sure without knowing where the module file is located.

Try and include the filepath in the application namespace and see if that helps.

Like in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/5180534